# Do I need to implement a Navigation Controller to make a UISearchViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working on my first iOS app and I'm realizing just right now that I don't have a navigation controller. Since I'm already pretty far in the app and not completely sure of how I would implement a navigation controller, I was wondering if I would need one in order to implement a search controller, meaning a `UITableViewController` with like a navigation bar on top.

Answer (score 1):

To implement a Navigation Controller you just need to select the View Controller in storyboard then Click up top Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller.  You could also just add a navigation bar to the top of the View Controller you are using.

These are the two options for adding a navigation bar, however, neither is required for adding a search bar.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add a navigation controller just to display a navigation bar. Navigation bar can be added to any `UIViewController`.

You can also add just the search controller in a navigation controller, without affecting your other view controllers. This will add a Navigation bar to the search controller and also allow you to navigate to (Push) other view controllers.

Comment: That is actually how I have it right now. However, like that I have some problem such as the fact that when I'm searching something and I clicked on one of the result cells I get an [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731032/warning-attempt-to-present-view-controller-on-which-is-already-presenting-ui/36735083?noredirect=1#comment61053447_36735083)

Comment: Which approach are you following - adding a Nav bar or adding a Nav controller ?

Comment: Now I'm trying to just keep what I already had and fix the bug I was talking about in the link I attached to the previous comment